# How to properly set Gain and Exposure properties in OPENCV videocapture class

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I am having trouble setting up opencv in C++ to manually change these properties, but every time I try I get the warning "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in OpenCV Code.exe" and an error is thrown.

Here is how I am setting it up (cap is my videocapture object):

cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE,0.5);

Comment: Just for kicks, try running your program as root, with `sudo ./YourApp` to see if it is a permissions issue. If so, state your OS.

Comment: I am running on a Windows 7 PC